# How to open the android "Priority only allows" screen

Tags: android, interruption

Is there an intent to open the android "Priority only allows" screen?
This is the screenshot I want to reach. Unfortunately, depending on the Android release, it might look very different. It is some confusion to the users to get to the right place:

[image]

For Android Pie is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the `Priority only allows` intent like this

```
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ZEN_MODE_PRIORITY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

I hope this helps you.

EDIT:

In the case of `Android Pie` you can try this

```
  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: By the way, in the first screen you only see the Priority mode, in the second (which belongs to Android Pie) it displays that and also some Do not disturb settings behavior. Is there a way to access that in another intent for devices earlier than Pie?

Comment: Please take a look at edited answer and tell me what you've got.

Comment: Excuse me, in Huawei using Android 8 I get the error message "no activity found to handle ZEN_MODE_PRIORITY_SETTINGS"